# How can I cleanly include an "Other" textbox in a radio button list in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I currently have a radio button list with an "Other" option.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Language, "English") English
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Language, "Spanish") Spanish
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Language, "Other") Other:
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OtherLanguage)
```

However, this setup requires an additional field in the model. If the user clicks "Other" and types in "French", for example, the model will contain:

```
Language: Other
OtherLanguage: French
```

I would like a cleaner approach where the model just contains `Language: French`. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Is using javascript/jquery acceptable?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Absolutely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Jquery

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Language) // assume this renders id="Language"
```

Then create your radio buttons (not using HtmlHelpers)

```
<input type="radio" name="language" value="English" /> // plus label
<input type="radio" name="language" value="Spanish" /> // plus label
....
```

In script

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function () { // or input[name="language"]
  $('#Language').val($(this).val());
}
```